# Can't update linux-modules-5.15.0-56-generic

Tags: apt, kernel, updates

I can't update linux-modules-5.15.0-56-generic.

When I tried from command line I get:

`sudo apt install linux-modules-5.15.0-56-generic`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.15.0-52 linux-headers-5.15.0-52-generic linux-image-5.15.0-52-generic
  linux-modules-5.15.0-52-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-52-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-modules-5.15.0-56-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/22.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 118 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 414347 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-modules-5.15.0-56-generic_5.15.0-56.62_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-5.15.0-56-generic (5.15.0-56.62) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): ZSTD_decompressStream error : Corrupted block detected 

dpkg-deb: error: <decompress> subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-5.15.0-56-generic_5.15.0-
56.62_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './lib/modules/5.15.0-56-generic/kernel/net/key/af_key.ko' to 
'/lib/modules/5.15.0-56-generic/kernel/net/key/af_key.ko.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or 
stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-5.15.0-56-generic_5.15.0-56.62_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

fix-broken also fails in same file and dpkg reports corrupted source file containing broken block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package that have been downloaded is corrupt:
`dpkg-deb (subprocess): ZSTD_decompressStream error : Corrupted block detected`

Try and remove your cache with `sudo apt clean` and then retry the install.

Comment: right answer. Modules installed properly. Thanks